# How to hide Ads From Certain Categories?

Tags: php, plugin-development

I'd like to hide our some ads codeblocks from appearing on certain categories/-also category posts- in Wordpress. How to do that?

I would like to post some content to certain category and I want to prevent some ads appearing on those category posts?

Comment: follow this link http://www.jeetblog.com/how-to-remove-ads-on-posts-in-certain-categories-in-wordpress/

Comment: Depending on your theme, available plugins and so on there are different approaches. So you'll have to be more specific about your setup. As it is now, your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: `<?php
if ( !in_category(5) && !in_category(10) ) {
?>
Your ad code here
<?php } ?>`   this code isnt working

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( !is_category(1469) && !in_category(1469) ):?>

AD CODE GOES HERE

<?php endif;?>
```

Above code worked:
It should put endif at the end.

Example: http://gameslopedy.com/full-game-downloads/test-post/